# How to map ember object hierarchy to Haxe

Tags: ember.js, haxe

I have just started to create Haxe externs (strictly typed class definitions)
based on the yuidoc output from the ember source.
Now I need help to understand how to implement the kind of mixing architecture special to Ember.

For example the `Ember.Object` extends the `Ember.CoreObject` - however I wasn't able to locate any constructor inside the latter - is there any direct call to `new Something()` in Ember at all?

Then `Ember.Object` uses `Ember.Observable` which in turn imports `cacheFor` from the ember-metal / lib / computed.js module - is this relation reflected inside the `data.json` output of yuidoc or will I need to parse the sources directly in order to collect all methods into my class definitions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there any direct call to new Something() in Ember at all?

For the most part, no. You're supposed to call `Class.create()` not `new Class()`.

> is this relation reflected inside the data.json output of yuidoc or will I need to parse the sources directly in order to collect all methods into my class definitions?

The data.json file should contain most of the documentation written. The problem you'll experience is that not everything is documented (mostly private API).

> Where can I find the Container Class API docs?

[In the source code.](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/container/lib/container.js)

Comment: Is there a reason this is not included in the yuidoc output?

Comment: Does the Container inherit any other class?

Comment: Where is InheritingDict defined?

Comment: 1. Yes, the container is considered private API I believe. Plus, it's not documented very well internally either. 2. No, I believe the Container class is straight up JS, using the prototype directly. 3. It was removed, but you can find the old code [here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/a6162631e1ec8abd7627784b33cd07483af40dce/packages/container/lib/inheriting_dict.js).